SQL Queries: the most common value in a column grouped by another column
Let's say I have a database employee.db, created as following:
# %% CREATE DATAFRAME
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Adam', 'Jane', 'Frank', 'Mary'],
        'Age': [35, 28, 42, 32, 35, 39],
        'Department': ['HR', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT', 'Sales', 'IT']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# %% CREATE A SQL DATABASE ENGINE
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///employee.db', echo=True)

# %% CONVERT THE DATA FRAME TO SQL
df.to_sql('employee', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# %% CLOSE THE CONNECTION
engine.dispose()

I'm trying to read the database, with
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import pandas as pd

# %% CREATE A SQL DATABASE ENGINE
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///employee.db', echo=True)

# %% QUERY THE SQL TABLE
with engine.connect() as conn:
    # INSERT SQL QUERIES HERE

# %% CLOSE THE CONNECTION
engine.dispose()

I would like to calculate the most common name per department. In case of department 'IT' the query have to display 'Jane'.

What is the issue?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current query attempt..

These are all fairly straight-forward queries. You should check the documentation for ORDER BY and aggregation functions.

calculate how many different departments are present without repetitions (expected output: 4 - ['HR', 'IT', 'Finance', 'Sales'])

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.Department)
FROM employee e;


the most frequent department (expected output: IT - 3 occurrences)

For this one you will want to aggregate the Department first, then take the top one.
SELECT e.Department, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM employee e
GROUP BY
  e.Department
ORDER BY
  count DESC
LIMIT 1;


the oldest employee (expected output: Adam - 42)

SELECT e.Name, e.Age
FROM employee e
ORDER BY
  e.Age DESC;

Do yourself a favour and don't store Age in a database, it changes the whole time. Instead store the DOB and calculate the age off that.
